# how to request camera and microphone access again using getUserMedia() after being denied

Tags: javascript, webrtc, microsoft-edge, media, tauri

how to request camera and microphone access again using getUserMedia() after being denied?

Is there any function that can reset browser settings to re-prompt again specifically for edge browser because I'm using Tauri to build a video conference desktop app that is based on webview2 similar to edge browser but there is no way to undo that if the user denies for the first time after that there is no going back and the app will be useless

```
  const getLocalPreview = async () => {
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true});
        return stream;
    } catch (error) {
      //this is when user don't allow media devices
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no api for this, see https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4434#issuecomment-1209259672

> The problem is that solutions are blocked by https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2427 and by extension https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2672

Until upstream support is available, the only solution to this is to edit/remove the WebView2 files in `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\<your-app-bundle-identifieer>\EBWebView\` directly, specifically the `\EBWebView\Default\Preferences` file. Unfortunately you have to do it in Rust *while no WebView2 Window is open*. Unless just telling your users to do it themselves works for you...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I attempted to remove the preferences file using javascript with the remove_file API from Tauri, but it did not work, and there are no docs on how to remove a file in rust. Could you please provide me with a code snippet in rust?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work in javascript, because the WebView2 processes must be closed for this to work.
Here's how you'd do it in rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_file.html